# TensorFlow: GNU Screen for IPython causes import error

Tags: ipython, tensorflow, gnu-screen

I've installed TensorFlow with GPU from source on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 system.
Using `ipython` results in successful tensorflow imports and training/testing with multiple GPUs.
However when I use `screen ipython`, I get the error:

`ImportError: libcudart.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I suspected this was a problem with environment variables, and found that indeed

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

returns `':/usr/local/cuda/lib64'` without screen and gets a `KeyError` with screen.

So I created `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/fix_ld_lib_path.py` with contents

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ':/usr/local/cuda/lib64'
```

and now `screen ipython` gives nearly the same environment variables (except for some that relate to terminal display that appear unrelated) but I still get the same import error as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen unsets various environment variables (including `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see [this Unix StackExchange answer for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43729/how-does-screen-impact-environment-variables)). As you've discovered, setting `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']` doesn't fix the `ImportError` because this environment variable must be set when the process launches. The easiest way to fix this is to modify your `screen` invocation as follows:

```
$ screen env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ipython
```

This will set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` within the screen session and it will take effect before `ipython` launches, as is needed.